# MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork causes crash (weird issue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, instruments

allocations before running 'extra loop'
[image: allocations before running 'crashing' loop]

The code:

```
// loading items to the array, there are no memory warnings after this is completed. The first allocations screenshot is after this code and before extra loop code.
NSMutableArray *albumCovers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (MPMediaQuery *query in queries) {
    NSArray *allCollections = [query collections];
    for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in allCollections) {
        MPMediaItemArtwork *value = [collection.representativeItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
                UIImage *image = [value imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
                if (image) {
                    [albumCovers addObject:image];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    _mediaCollections = [NSArray arrayWithArray:artworkedCollections];
    _albumCovers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:albumCovers];
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
// !!!!! extra loop - from here the memory starts to grow and never release
for (i=0; i< 800; i++) {
    UIImage * coverImage = [_albumCovers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [veryTemp setImage:coverImage]; // exactly this line adds to the memory. with this line commented, there is no problem.
}
```

allocations after running 'extra loop'
[image: allocations before running 'crashing' loop]

and to clarify, call stack with only-obj-c on and system libraries off (if i turn them on, the highest % is 0.9% per heaviest method)
[image: call stack after extra loop]

I've made some research, and found at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994039/imageio-in-instruments), that these `VM:ImageIO_PNG_Data` are usually comming from `[UIImage imageNamed:]`, however as you can see i don't use this method, i'm just getting the reference from `MPMediaItemCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that UIImage usually keeps just a ref(CGImageRef), which is a small one. After displaying items, CGImageRef was 'injected' with information. As a result the table was growing all the time.

The simple but not the most beautiful solution was to use the code:

```
NSArray = @[obj1, obj2, obj3]; // where obj is custom NSObject and has a UIImage property
```

instead of:

```
NSArray = @[img1, img2, img3]; // where img is of UIImage type
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in `@autorelease` pool?

Also, why are you setting the image for veryTemp (I assume it's a `UIImageView`) 800 times in `[veryTemp setImage:coverImage];` ?

Finally:

```
[_albumCovers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You're getting the image object at the exact same index (`indexPath.row`) in your loop. I am not quite sure what you're trying to achieve in your code?

Comment: 1. I add it to the UIImageView 800 times only for testing purpouses. Usually the images are used in collection view, but i wanted to make sure it was the image issue not collection view one. 2. IndexPath.row is changing because it is a part of larger code. The 'extra loop' is a different method than the code above ;) 3. Autorelease was already tested and doesn't help.