# Experiencing memory leak using UICollectionView and MPMediaItemArtwork

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, mpmediaitem

I'm building a basic music player application, making use of Apple's MediaPlayer to access the iPod library.  In one of my views, I use UICollectionView to display album art for all albums in the library. When scrolling I'm getting huge increases in memory usage, which I expect, but the usage never decreases, and eventually the app crashes due to memory pressure, topping out at about a few hundred mb in the Xcode debugger.

this is essentially the code I'm using to configure each collectionView cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(ALBUM_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumCollectionViewCell
    cell.configureWithAlbum(albumItems[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}


func configureWithAlbum(album: MPMediaItemCollection){
    guard let representItem = album.representativeItem else{
        return
    }

    if let albumTitle = representItem.albumTitle{
        if let artwork = AlbumsCollectionViewDataSource.sharedInstance.artworkDict[albumTitle]{
            backgroundImageView.image = artwork.imageWithSize(backgroundImageView.frame.size)
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have tried to use NSCache to cache the album art, as well as override `prepareForReuse` and set `backgroundImageView.image = nil`, but this seems to have no effect.   Additionally, I have a tableview that similarly makes use of a small UIImageviews for cover art which seems to be causing similar issues.

Is it possible that I am obviously overlooking something? For a few hundred cells with small album art I figure this should be possible without a ton of memory usage.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed- not sure why but `MPMediaItemArtwork.imageWithSize(size:CGSize)` method was constantly reallocating memory every time it was called. Instead, I subclassed `NSObject` with UIImage property and stored all the artwork in an array of those `NSObject`s on the initial load of the collectionViewDataSource, and passed it to `configureWithAlbum`.

see [MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork causes crash (weird issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182495/mpmediaitempropertyartwork-causes-crash-weird-issue)