# MPMediaItemArtwork imageWithSize: memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, mpmediaitem

When one calls `imageWithSize:` on any `MPMediaItemArtwork` object, even after all references to the associated `MPMediaItem` and `UIImage` have been dropped, the memory is still held onto as if there is a magical reference gripping onto it.

I have created a whole separate project to test this specific leak and I am very concerned that this is an issue with the API internally and that there is nothing I can do about it.

Now let's get into some good ol' code. One view controller and 3 simple steps will reproduce this issue. My code below does this:

1. Creates an array for the images and gets an array of `MPMediaItemCollection` objects (with each collection having only one song in it, for worst-case scenario testing)
2. For every representative `MPMediaItem` within each `MPMediaItemCollection`, an album art image is generated with a `CGSize` of 500x500.
3. An `NSTimer` is fired after 3 seconds which simply sets all arrays associated with the images to `nil`

ViewController.m:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *representativeImageArray;
@property NSMutableArray *collectionArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)letItGo {
    self.representativeImageArray = nil;
    self.collectionArray = nil;

    NSLog(@"Let go.");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.representativeImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.collectionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[MPMediaQuery songsQuery].collections];

    for(int i = 0; i < self.collectionArray.count; i++){
        MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [self.collectionArray objectAtIndex:i];
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < collection.count; i1++){
            MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [collection representativeItem];
            UIImage *image = [representativeItem.artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
            if(image){
                [self.representativeImageArray addObject:image];
            }
        }
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(letItGo)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

    NSLog(@"Got %ld items for collectionArray (%ld images).", self.collectionArray.count, self.representativeImageArray.count);
}

@end
```

For 1210 images generated from 1214 items (with a size of 500x500), here is a graph of the memory usage after running for a bit:

[image: Memory use for 1210 images with imageWithSize]

Compared to a graph of the memory usage if not calling `imageWithSize:` at all:

[image]

Now, I have seen people previously suggest using the `MPMediaItemArtwork`'s `CGSize` from its `bounds` property. So, let's do this instead.

Let's change

```
UIImage *image = [representativeItem.artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
```

to

```
UIImage *image = [representativeItem.artwork imageWithSize:representativeItem.artwork.bounds.size];
```

Now, after running the same code as in ViewController.m though with this one change, we get this for memory usage:

[image]

Yes, the arrays associated with the images were dropped, as in the previous two runs. Though the memory stays hovering around 70 MB regardless, and there seems to be no way to go back down to ~10 MB without completely restarting the app.

This is an interesting problem I've been battling all day. Personally, I am more used to managing memory myself coming from a C background and knowing all memory leaks were basically going to be my fault. Sorry if something here completely flew over my head.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a tonne for reading!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182495/mpmediaitempropertyartwork-causes-crash-weird-issue ?

Comment: @Larme, thanks for sharing. I've tried that solution and I still get the same problem. http://pastebin.com/z8KuKypW

Comment: I am seeing very similar behavior.  I have a table view of time that reference MPMediaItems and each cell has an UIImageView that is filled with artwork for the media item.   Scrolling through the table causes huge memory use that remains even though the actual allocated cell count is quite reasonable.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @joey unfortunately I believe this is a bug within Apple's MediaPlayer framework that cannot be fixed by us mere mortals. It seems quite a funny "coincidence" that they cause bugs like this, and the iOS 11.3/12.0 lag, causing users to switch to the Apple Music app ;)

Comment: yeah, I spent about 1.5 days trying to figure out a workaround and couldn't. Also noticed that this problem has existed since around 2009. Yeah, it's probably a very big "coincidence" lol